# Two character Integer to char?

Tags: c#

So I am making a program that calculates X in an expression, e.g if I type 2*x=6 then it will say x = 3.
My code:

```
  string[] exps = textBox1.Text.Split('=');
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
        string s = exps[0].Replace('x', Convert.ToChar(i.ToString())); //<- problem is there
        var v = dt.Compute(s, "");
        if (int.Parse(v.ToString()) == int.Parse(exps[1]))
        {
              listBox1.Items.Add("x = " + i);
              break;
        }
  }
```

But I have a problem when X is more than 9 (so it is two characters) e.g 12 or 27, It can't convert it to char. Can you help me how can I do this easier? Thank you!

And sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use the `Replace(char, char)` overload. There is also a [`Replace(string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) overload:

```
string s = exps[0].Replace("x", i.ToString());
```

You are probably aware of this already, but your way of solving equations only works for a very specific kind of equations. Mainly it has these problems:

- the solution must be an integer between 0 and 49
- there must be only one solution
- Multiplication must be clearly indicated i.e. `5x` doesn't mean 5 times x.
- The right hand side must be an integer. This problem can be easily fixed by calling `Compute` with `exps[1]` (with the `x` substitutes in of course).

Comment: Can you explain me how can I make it with float numbers, e.g 5.10+x=5.20 ?

Comment: @Scholler then you can’t use your current method - trying a bunch of values and see which works. You probably need some kind of algorithm to rearrange the equation. The problem becomes much much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of char just convert it to string:

```
exps[0].Replace("x", i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a datatable with two columns

(1) with column name 'X', this will keep value and

(2) a Computed column which will have expression.

Sample Code:

```
        var dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("X", typeof(float)));

        var exprCol=new DataColumn("Expr");
        exprCol.Expression="X+10";

        dt.Columns.Add(exprCol);

        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["X"] = 5;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        var calculatedValue=row["Expr"];
```